# Hibernate cannot handle sequences with same name in differen schemas

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

After upgrading from 5.4.7 to 5.4.10 it looks like hibernate cannot handle two sequences with the same name in different db schemas anymore.

I have this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG", schema = "INFOP_FAHRPLAN")
public class VmLaufRichtung {

    public static final String VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG_TABLE = "INFOP_FAHRPLAN.VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG";


    @Id
    @Digits(integer = 15, fraction = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "InfopFahrplan.seqVmLaufRichtung", schema = "INFOP_FAHRPLAN", sequenceName = "SEQ_VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "InfopFahrplan.seqVmLaufRichtung")
    @Column(name = ID)
    private Long id;
}
```

In an other schema, there's a sequence with a the same name `SEQ_VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG`.
When my spring boot application starts I do get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [SEQ_VM_LAUF_RICHTUNG] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
```

This happens because it's picking up the wrong sequence, which has an other imcrement size.

I tried to fix the problem by setting

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

but that did not change anything.

With hibernate 5.4.7 everyhting is working fine.

Did I miss something or is this a hibernate bug after all?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this is indeed a hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13322